Does it matter what wand I pick in Hogwarts Legacy?
I've now been given a choice to pick my first wand in Hogwarts Legacy, but do I need to think carefully about what wand I choose?

Does it matter what wand I choose?
Can I change my wand later in the game or would I be stuck with this wand?

The wand you choose is nothing but a narrative choice. The wand, such as wood type, core type, flexibility, and length, don't impact gameplay or your character's abilities. So, there is no need to stress about the decision as it will not affect your gameplay performance.
But once you choose your wand, you cannot change it later in the game.
